# Rendering nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

My question is very trivial but I've got completely lost.

I'm using Reactjs. I've got an array of objects like this:

```
const modules = [
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 1,
    name: "Name 1",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 2",
    id: 2,
    name: "Name 2",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 3,
    name: "Name 3",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },

  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 4,
    name: "Name 4",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
{
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 5,
    name: "Name 5",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to render it as:

```
Topic 1:
- Name 1
- Name 4

Topic 2:
- Name 2

Topic 3:
- Name 3
- Name 5
```

So far I've tried to use LoDash _.groupBy and juggled some mapKeys, mapValues but as I said at the beginning - I've completely lost. Please, help me to find the best solution...

https://codesandbox.io/s/8p21n6p09l -> here is a sandbox where I need to implement the solution.
A source object is in App.js and I've tried to use LoDash in components -> thematicArea.jsx Hope it'll help in helping me ; )

Comment: Can you show what you did with lodash that is not working?

Comment: At first I did 
orderedModules = _.groupBy(this.modules, thematicArea => {
    return thematicArea.thematicArea;
  });
to get order it like {Topic 1: Array(2), Topic 2: Array(1), Topic 3: Array(2)}

I can get thematicArea by Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.orderedModules)

and tried to get names by 
names = _.mapValues(this.orderedModules, e => _.mapValues(e, f => f.name))

but...it's clearly wrong. Have no good clue how to mix it.

Comment: Please edit your question with what your tried, the formatting is better.

Comment: Added sandbox where it can be cleanerr explained. I've tried to implement my solutions in components -> thematicArea.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make an Object which's keys are the `thematicArea`s and which's values are an array of the `names`, after that just return in the wanted format:

```js
const modules=[{thematicArea:"Topic 1",id:1,name:"Name 1",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 2",id:2,name:"Name 2",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 3",id:3,name:"Name 3",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 1",id:4,name:"Name 4",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 3",id:5,name:"Name 5",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]}]

let themes = {};

modules.forEach(mod => {
  // if there already is an Key named `mod.thematicArea` put the current name in it
  if(themes[mod.thematicArea]) themes[mod.thematicArea].push(mod.name);
  // else create that property and make it an array containing the mod.name
  else themes[mod.thematicArea] = [mod.name];
});

console.log(themes)

/**themes = Object.keys(themes).map(key => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h3>{key}</h3>
    <ul>
    {themes[key].map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
});**/
```

After that you can render it:

```js
const modules=[{thematicArea:"Topic 1",id:1,name:"Name 1",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 2",id:2,name:"Name 2",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 3",id:3,name:"Name 3",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 1",id:4,name:"Name 4",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]},{thematicArea:"Topic 3",id:5,name:"Name 5",details:["Lorem ipsum","Lorem ipsum 2"]}]

let themes = {};

modules.forEach(mod => {
  // if there already is an Key named `mod.thematicArea` put the current name in it
  if(themes[mod.thematicArea]) themes[mod.thematicArea].push(mod.name);
  // else create that property and make it an array containing the mod.name
  else themes[mod.thematicArea] = [mod.name];
});

themes = Object.keys(themes).map(key => {
  return (
    <div>
    <h3>{key}</h3>
    <ul>
    {themes[key].map(name => <li>{name}</li>)}
    </ul>
    </div>
  )
});

ReactDOM.render(
  themes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Seriously? Simply as that? Just can believe I couldn't figure it out by myself - I'm a little bit embarassed : P I hope it'll work after implementation to my bigger project ; )
Thanks a lot! You're the best!

Comment: No Problem :-) I'm currently learning React, so this was a nice way to apply my knowledge ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to do the group-by operation.

```js
const modules = [
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 1,
    name: "Name 1",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 2",
    id: 2,
    name: "Name 2",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 3,
    name: "Name 3",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },

  {
    thematicArea: "Topic 1",
    id: 4,
    name: "Name 4",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  },
{
    thematicArea: "Topic 3",
    id: 5,
    name: "Name 5",
    details: [
      "Lorem ipsum",
      "Lorem ipsum 2"
    ]
  }
]

const grouped = modules.reduce((groups, module) => {
    if (!groups[module.thematicArea]) {
        groups[module.thematicArea] = [];
    }
    groups[module.thematicArea].push(module.name);
    return groups;
}, {});

console.log(grouped);
```